# Nonmodal pop-up vs application-modal pop-up

Tags: gui-design, popup

I am not sure whether the "join our mailing list" pop-up shown when the page "https://www.lemonadela.com/" first appears is considered a Nonmodal pop-up or a application-modal pop-up.

Could you please help?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests information about a UI element in a specific website.

Comment: Are you asking for terminology here? Wikipedia explains "modal" as "It creates a mode that disables the main window but keeps it visible, with the modal window as a child window in front of it." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what either "Nonmodal pop-up or a application-modal pop-up" are.

it's modal, so that rules out Nonmodal pop-up and this is a website not an application so that rules out application modal pop up.

And pop-ups by their very nature are modal so saying something is a modal pop up is like saying a modal modal or a pop up pop up.

Anyway, it looks like its an on-load modal lightbox.